# Can't make click event of button created in code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Button1.Click
Panel1.Controls.Clear()
Dim patiekalai = New Button()
Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai)
patiekalai.Location = New Point(0, 0)
patiekalai.Size = New Size(80, 50)
patiekalai.Image = Image.FromFile("../M/Karštieji patiekalai.jpg")

Private Sub Patiekalai_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Patiekalai.Click
```

I get error while trying to add a Click event handler for my dynamically created button patiekalai:

Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

Comment: Maybe share the error code don't you think?

Comment: Error 1 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

Comment: Add this info to your question;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because the button does not exist until Button1 is clicked, at run-time.  What you want to do is add a handler as well at run-time.

Remove the "Handles" from the "Patiekalai_Click" method.  Then, after you create your control at run-time: "patiekalai.Image = Image...." add this line

```
AddHandler patiekalai.Click AddressOf Patiekalai_Click
```

This tells the click event of the button to call the selected method.